# Incompatible block pointer... error when block

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I implemented [MKInputBox](https://github.com/planetexpress69/MKInputBoxView), and I'm trying to use a block statement. Here is the code: (It's in their [sample project](https://github.com/planetexpress69/MKInputBoxView/blob/master/MKInputBoxViewExample/ViewController.m#L38):)

```
alertView.customise = ^(UITextField *textField) {

};
```

I get an error saying the following:

> ```
> Incompatible block pointer types assigning to 'UITextField *(^)(UITextField *__strong)' from 'void (^)(UITextField *__strong)'
> ```

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Your block has to return a `UITextField`

Comment: oh!! How could I have missed that!!